# Svelte/SvelteKit: Dynamic import of components with variable

Tags: import, svelte, dynamic-import, sveltekit

I want to dynamically import components without importing a specific component.
I want to set the component name with a variable, received from the store:

```
<script lang="ts">
    // SVELTE
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    // STORE
    import { dynamicComponent } from '$stores/dynamicTitle';


    $: $dynamicComponent;
    console.log($dynamicComponent)

    
    let renderDynamicComponent
    

    onMount(async () => {       
        const importValue = (await import(`../../lib/components/Home/DynamicComponents/${String($dynamicComponent)}.svelte`)).default;
        // const importValue = (await import(`../../lib/components/Home/DynamicComponents/IntroSectionCustom.svelte`)).default;
        renderDynamicComponent = importValue
    });

<svelte:component this={renderDynamicComponent}/>
```

But I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/src/lib/components/Home/DynamicComponents/Intro-Section-Custom.svelte
```

I do not understand. From the error, it seems to be the right path ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Svelte + the bundler currently support dynamically generated paths:

```js
let thing = 'Thing';
Thing = (await import(`./${thing}.svelte`)).default; // this won't work
Thing = (await import(`./Thing.svelte`)).default; // this will work
```

limitation of the bundler.
github issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6702

Answer (score 3):

The Rollup plugin [@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars) might be of help here. I haven't used it with SvelteKit specifically, but it worked fine with standard Svelte with Vite as bundler.

```js
// Example.svelte
function importLocale(locale) {
  return import(`./locales/${locale}.js`);
}
```

```js
// vite.config.js
import dynamicImportVars from '@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars';

export default (mode) =>
  defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      dynamicImportVars({
        include: './src/Example.svelte'
      })
    ]
});
```

SvelteKit uses Vite behind the scenes, but has its own configuration format. In `svelte.config.js`, pass `dynamicImportVars()` to the `config.vite.plugins` key:

```js
// svelte.config.js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      dynamicImportVars({
        include: './src/Example.svelte'
      })
    ]
  }
};

export default config;
```

Please take note of the [limitations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars#limitations) mentioned in the README of the Rollup plugin.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing [does work](https://svelte.dev/repl/16b375da9b39417dae837b5006799cb4?version=3.25.0) if not using import vars. When adding an import variable you need make your `renderDynamicComponent` identifier reactive. So instead of this:

```js
let renderDynamicComponent
```

Do this:

```html
$: renderDynamicComponent = null
```

This will allow `svelte:component` to render your imported component with dynamic path variable. This seems to be a special case when using [dynamic import vars](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations) with Vite.