# Can I make custom nested slugs in SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

Lets say I have a page to show information about some fictive persons, which loads dynamic data from some database.

One typical way to do this in SvelteKit is by creating a folder and file in the */routes* directory, like this: ***/person/[id].svelte***

However, I would like to have informative nested slugs based on different parameters, e.g. ***/country/city/street/name***

Then I have an array of "persons" in js that I can match these slugs against, get the correct id and the correct svelte component to render the person in, eg. ***person.svelte***.

[Edit]

In the same project, I might have other categories and different depths of nesting, which might look like: ***carcompany/navigation/navigation/car/model***

[/Edit]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is one of the best practices, but as long as the documentation suggests, and I've done something similar in my projects, yes you definitely can. If you create

**/[country]/[city]/[street]/[name].svelte**

You can retrieve the params in the URL object of Sveltekit.

For exeample,

/south_korea/seoul/yeoksamdong/james will return

```
 ...
  params : { country: 'south_korea', city: 'seoul', street: 'yeoksamdong', name: 'james'}
 ...
```

This is accessible in the load function, or from the 'page' store

```
export async function load(event) {

  event.url.params // returns params.
  
  return { props : {} }
}
```

or

```
import { page } from '$app/pages'

$page.url.params // returns params. notice '$'
```

The main difference of these are if they can be accessible from client side, or server side. However, you can refer from both sides if you return a prop from the load function.

```
<script context="module">
export async function load(event) {
  
  return { props : {
     params: event.url.params 
   } }
}
</script>
<script>
export let params;
</script>
{params.name} -> james
```

Comment: While technically your answer could work in my initial sample, I am looking for a solution where I can add a completely custom route, with different depths based on the structure of my project (which might or might not include sub categories, altering the route depth).

E.g. in Vue 3 I could just tell the router that "this/completely/custom/route" should load X component with Y properties in Z slot/view.

Comment: This sounds like a dynamic import. I am not the expert, but have you tried to use 'catchall', and parse the URL to show a specific component based on it? I would do that if I encounter the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295473/svelte-sveltekit-dynamic-import-of-components-with-variable I am sure others have a better idea, as I am not fully accustomed with the route system of Sveltekit.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am also contemplating [page1]/[page2]/[page3]/[page4]/[page5]/(...) and let all layout and logic be in components outside the router. It just feels awfully wrong though. Some kind of route alias system would have been cool, where I could say that a"/friendly/informative/custom/path" is just an alias for the route "/person/50101", and SvelteKit would act like the route was the latter.

Comment: I am on the same page with you. That looks a bit awful, but seems to be the only way. But wouldn't it be better to just have a catchall, and split it instead of awfully setting up multiple nested folders? If I understood what catchall does, src/route/[...catchall].svelte will handle both "/friendly/informative/custom/path" and "/person/50101".